# How can I configure a String column to use 'char' as the unit of size instead of 'byte' in DataNucleus

Tags: oracle11g, jdo, datanucleus, oracle-xe

I'm using DataNucleus as my persistence layer (JDO) and am forced to use Oracle 11g as a database (using 11g XE for development). Unfortunately since version 11.2 the default length semantics (`NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`) for `VARCHAR` columns have been set to `byte` instead of `char` which means that all columns that only provide a size will result in a type definition like this:

```
VARCHAR2(50 byte)
```

instead of:

```
VARCHAR2(50 char)
```

From Oracle's perspective the solution is threefold:

1. declare a unit in your size definiton (what I'm trying to achieve with JDO metadata)
2. alter the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` attribute on every session
3. alter the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` attribute globally (which seems not to work with the "Express Edition", I've already wasted a whole day on this)

I've searched the Mapping and Persistence Documention up and down to find metadata attributes that let me do this. I can specify `jdbcType`, `sqlType` and of course `length` for a column. But no unit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can do it by creating your table. so id a table is already created and the datatype of a column was `VARCHAR2(50 byte)` you could try to do a migration into a new column that is `VARCHAR2(50 char)`

Comment: @hotfix thanks for your answer. I'm aware that I can create a schema from hand and migrate data that way. But I'm looking for a general solution that lets `DataNucleus` do all the work. I need this to work automatically.

Comment: so why not just create a column as varchar2(200) if your string could have more than 100 Bytes?

Comment: @hotfix Because there's no reliable measure of what I can store in that column. Unicode characters range from 2 to 4 bytes. The content is generated by users.

Comment: I understand, but if you say that your string can be up to 100 characters long. if each character would be 4 bytes, then you can set 400 as the length